# How to make a temporary checkpoint (not a commit)?

Tags: git

I am working on a project and I am about to do something experimental.

I am not ready to make a commit however.

Is it possible to make a checkpoint that I can revert to? Git stash does not appear to be appropriate in this case as I want to work on the same branch.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why do you want to work on the same branch? Make a new branch, say `git checkout -b experimental/ni_shrubbery`, commit on it, then either merge it back or don't. You can always get back to your `master` or `develop` or `feature/shrubbery`, whatever you're developing on. Branches exist *exactly* for this scenario. Just don't push that branch out, and all your work is local until you merge into a branch that you do push out.

Answer (score 4):

Local commit is exactly what you want: a checkpoint you can revert to. Local commits can be amended/squashed/removed before pushing them publicly so you don't need to 'be ready to make a commit'. You have to be ready to make a push (e.g. squash all your local commits into 1 commit before pushing). 
You can read more about local commit modifications in the [ProGit book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) (I link to Rewriting-History chapter, but suggest that you read all the chapters)

Answer (score 3):

Main drawback of committing your changes - whether to a temporary experimental branch or not - is that one loses track of overall extent of work - the combined changes performed up to the checkpoint.

In an IDE, I personally use IntelliJ IDEA, I can see colour blocks in the gutter (near scrollbar) which indicate which lines were edited or added. *Deleted* blocks of code are indicated by a little clickable triangle, and I can easily see what those deleted lines were by clicking on it.

All this neat IDE stuff works only up to the point you commit your changes.

So, what I would like to suggest is a combination of the above answers - i.e. *do commit* often and early, potentially edit/rewrite your commit history before pushing/publishing your changes to the remote. *Also*, after you've committed you perform a **soft** reset. `git reset --soft HEAD^` This way, you will (1) have a commit in your git repo that you can roll back to, if needed. (Use `git reflog` to get at the hash of the commit, should you later need to revert back to it.) You also (2) get to keep all changes as un-committed so that your IDE can show you the visual indicators of change.

If you make really bad changes you want to quickly abandon, do a hard reset back to your most recent good checkpoint, then a soft reset to the point where you started making your *big* changes.

Answer (score 0):

Just commit. You can always roll it back, or combine commits when you're happy.
So long as you dont push it to your remote repositories no-one else will see it.

My git motto is "commit early and commit often - clean it up before pushing".

Another option is to create a branch. Then all your experimental commits will live apart from the master commits. you can them merge or rebase that once you're done experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

Make a commit. Give it a message like "interim commit" or something. Then cut a branch and start work from there. If you want to avoid the latest changes (i.e. the ones you just committed), cut a branch from `HEAD^` and work from there.

If you're happy with the state of affairs after your experiment, you can move your `master` (or whatever branch you were on) to the current `HEAD` thereby droppping your interim commit. If you want the interim commit, go back to `master`, reset to `HEAD^`, rework it, commit and then merge your experimental branch into `master`.

If you don't like your experimental work, simply drop that branch, go back master and reset to `HEAD^`.

Commits are very light and it's perfectly fine to use them in this fashion.